# Integrating Qt C++ with lp_solve - compiler error

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, mingw, lpsolve

In my project I have to solve an Integer Linear Programming problem, so I have decided to integrate [lp_solve solver package](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) with Qt 4.8.4 mingw32 compiler on my Windows 7 Platform. I am statically compiling my standalone Qt application.

I have followed [this](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) advice on Statically linking my application with lp_solve (implicit linking).
- I have downloaded the header files mentioned and included their path in my .pro file.
- I have downloaded the liblpsolve55.lib file and included the library in my .pro file.

Additions to my project file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/ -lliblpsolve55
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/ -lliblpsolve55d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/liblpsolve55.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/liblpsolve55d.lib

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/ -llpsolve55

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32
```

Moreover, Qt Autocomplete is recognizing those header files.

However when I include the following line in my code, I get a bunch of warnings and errors.

```
int demo()
{
  lprec *lp;
  lp = make_lp( 0, 4); // This line gives me errors

  /*...*/
  return(0);
}
```

Compiler Output:

```
14:07:09: Running steps for project EZDraft...
14:07:09: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:07:09: Starting: "C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft-build-Unnamed_Microsoft_Windows_SDK_for_Windows_7_7_1_7600_0_30514_x86-Default_build_Debug'
g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\PanelDraw.exe object_script.PanelDraw.Release  -L"c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain release\myicon_res.o -LC:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/ -lliblpsolve55 -LC:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32/ -llpsolve55 -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lmsimg32 -lQtCore -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:uuid.lib ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:LIBCMT ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-defaultlib:OLDNAMES ' unrecognized
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_lib.obj):../lp_lib.c:(.text[_performiteration]+0x46f): undefined reference to `_allrem'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(commonlib.obj):../shared/commonli:(.text[_gcd]+0xac): undefined reference to `_alldiv'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(commonlib.obj):../shared/commonli:(.text[_gcd]+0xb9): undefined reference to `_allmul'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_MPS.obj):../lp_MPS.c:(.text[_MPS_readex@20]+0xc): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_utils.obj):../lp_utils.c:(.text[_roundToPrecision]+0xd1): undefined reference to `_allmul'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_price.obj):../lp_price.c:(.text[_makePriceLoop]+0x2e): undefined reference to `_allrem'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_params.obj):../lp_params.c:(.text[_write_params@12]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_params.obj):../lp_params.c:(.text[_write_params1]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft_10_09_2013/../../../../../../Users/Abhishek/Downloads/lp_solve_5.5.2.0_dev_win32//liblpsolve55.lib(lp_params.obj):../lp_params.c:(.text[_read_params@12]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\PanelDraw.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/EZDraft-build-Unnamed_Microsoft_Windows_SDK_for_Windows_7_7_1_7600_0_30514_x86-Default_build_Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
14:07:15: The process "C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project EZDraft (kit: Unnamed-Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1.7600.0.30514) (x86))
When executing step 'Make'
```

Any guidelines on how I can tackle the above errors shall be very helpful. I have googled for the above errors, but I am not able to get a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems from this [link](http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/Error-message-in-linking-Lp-solve-to-Dev-C-td3459.html) that with mingW I will have to re-compile the lpsolve .lib for my specific environment.

I have worked around this by resorting to shared DLL (implicit linking) procedure. It compiles without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured for me also. I have re-compiled the lpsolve lib with the Qt MinGW. (Version Qt 5.5, MinGW 4.9.2) The files can be downloaded at:

Windows-https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c8WhuA6Nq1Ynk0WmhaNXp0Uk0/view?usp=sharing
Unix-https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c8WhuA6Nq1RWRWS1AxRnhsSDQ/view?usp=sharing

My code for the linking (statical):

```
#
# LP Solver
#

unix {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_unix
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_unix
    LIBS += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_win/liblpsolve55.so
}

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_win
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_win
    LIBS += $$PWD/../MarbleCommon/MinNearConv/lp_solver_win/liblpsolve55.a
}
```